# custom code style for inline templates in intellij

Tags: angularjs, intellij-idea, ide

I'm having an hard time trying to ask idea to keep my code style on certain conditions.

The use case is really simple : When declaring inline templates in angular, i'd like to keep the string concatenation indented "hmtl-like", aka :

```
return {
    restrict    : "E",
    require     : "?ngModel",
    transclude  : true,
    replace     : true,
    template    : '' +
    '<div class="tl-checkbox">' +
        '<div class="tl-checkbox-container">' +
            '<div class="tl-checkbox-icon"></div>' +
        '</div>' +
        '<div class="tl-checkbox-label" ng-transclude></div>' +
    '</div>'
}
```

But when applying code styles, this become flattened :

```
    return {
    restrict    : "E",
    require     : "?ngModel",
    transclude  : true,
    replace     : true,
    template    : '' +
    '<div class="tl-checkbox">' +
    '<div class="tl-checkbox-container">' +
    '<div class="tl-checkbox-icon"></div>' +
    '</div>' +
    '<div class="tl-checkbox-label" ng-transclude></div>' + 
    '</div>'
}
```

Which is just simply unreadable, unmaintainable and ugly.

The "workaround" I actually use is to insert empty spaces at the start of the lines :

```
return {
        restrict    : "E",
        require     : "?ngModel",
        transclude  : true,
        replace     : true,
        template    : '' +
        '<div class="tl-checkbox">' +
        '    <div class="tl-checkbox-container">' +
        '        <div class="tl-checkbox-icon"></div>' +
        '    </div>' +
        '    <div class="tl-checkbox-label" ng-transclude></div>' +
        '</div>'

}
```

But this insert empty text node in the template, and this is basically less pretty than without spacing.

My question is : is there a way to make idea understand that I want my custom indentation preserved for string concatenation while keeping the code style / fix indent for the rest of the file ?

Edit : before this is answered : no, using templateUrl instead of inline templating is not an acceptable answer, they behave slightly differently in complex layouts (sync linking for template vs async linking for templateUrl )

Comment: Not really an answer, but maybe you can use ES6 with template strings. Intellij supports this very well